# Copy files containing a word and not containing other. / grep not working with for loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, grep

I am new to Linux and got stuck when I tried to used pipe grep or find commands. I need to find a file with:

- name pattern request_q*_t*.xml
- contains "Phrase 1"
- not contains "word 2" copy it to specific location.

I tried pipe grep command to locate the file and than copy.

```
for filename in $(grep --include=request_q*_t*.xml -li '"phrase 1"' $d/ | xargs grep -L '"word 2"')
do
    echo "coping file: '$filename'"
    cp $filename $outputpath
    filefound=true
done
```

When I tried this grep command in command line its working fine

```
grep --include=request_q*_t*.xml -li '"phrase 1"' $d/ | xargs grep -L '"word 2"'
```

but I am getting error in for loop. for some reason output of grep command is

```
(Standard Input)
(Standard Input)
(Standard Input)
(Standard Input)
```

1. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
2. what is the efficient way to do it.. Its a huge filesystem I have to search in.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "request_q*_t*.xml" -exec sh -c "if grep -q phrase\ 1 {} && ! grep -q word\ 2 {} ;then cp {} /path/to/somewhere/;fi;" \;
```

Comment: how I can substitute variable in place of phrase\ 1 and word\ 2?  I am using following : find shellscript\GU\ -name "rest_request.t*.q*.json" -exec sh -c 'if grep -q "$includecondition" {} && grep -Lq "$excludeCondition" ;then cp {} shellscript/GU/;fi;' \;                                   But its not working. the words I am looking for contains space and double quotes.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWK for this in combination with `xargs`. The problem is that you have to read all files completely as they cannot contain that single string, but you can also terminate early if that string is found:

```
awk '(FNR==1){if(a) print fname; fname=FILENAME; a=0}
     /Phrase 1/{a=1}
     /Word 2/{a=0;nextfile}
     END{if(a) print fname}' request_q*_t*.xml \
    | xargs -I{} cp "{}" "$outputpath"
```

If you want to store `"Phrase 1"` and `"Word 2"` in variables, you can use:

```
awk -v include="Phrase 1" -v exclude="Word 2"             \
     '(FNR==1){if(a) print fname; fname=FILENAME; a=0}
      ($0~include){a=1}
      ($0~exclude){a=0;nextfile}
      END{if(a) print fname}' request_q*_t*.xml           \
 | xargs -I{} cp "{}" "$outputpath"
```

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-only for `nextfile`. Quote `"$outputpath"`.

Comment: @EdMorton I have quoted the `"$outputpath"`, but I am confused about the `nextfile` thing. Confused in the sense that it was [accepted](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607) as part of POSIX in 2012 but I cannot find it in the [POSIX standard](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607).

Comment: I haven't heard of any plans for it to become part of POSIX, but then I usually don't until it is.

Answer (score -1):

You can nest the `$()` constructs:

```
for filename in $( grep -L '"word 2"' $(grep --include=request_q*_t*.xml -li '"phrase 1"' $d/ ))
do
    echo "coping file: '$filename'"
    cp $filename $outputpath
    filefound=true
done
```

Comment: that contains multiple bugs and anti-patterns. I understand you're trying to put a bandaid on the OPs script, but that script has 2 broken legs and a sucking chest wound.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm wondering what the legs are and which one is the chest wound.

Comment: It was more of an overall assessment of the condition of the patient and how useful a bandaid would be :-)

Comment: Constructive criticism would be appreciated.  If you don't have any....